# CMD Command only works when entered manually but not when used in file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I wanted to use
`ping -n 1 8.8.8.8 | findstr /r /c:"[0-9] *ms"`
to check if a internet connection is possible, before going forward in my code. But it does not work, when used in a file.

When i enter this command in a new command prompt manually it works as expected. When it is used in a file it gets 'kinda stuck' at this line and does nothing, as if it would wait for something that never happens. Any ideas on what this problem is and/or how to approach it? Thanks

Comment: `.bat` and `.cmd`, tested both. Both with the same result: seemingly "waiting" and not progressing

Comment: I created a seperate file just to test this and exlclude other things: in this one there is only the ping command followed by a 'pause'. But as i cant see the "press any key to continue" prompt, i dont think this is the problem

Comment: its called `test.bat` and `test.cmd` respectively

Comment: I cannot see anything wrong with that line. is there any file in that directory called ping? I suggest you change your script to this: `ping.exe -n 1 8.8.8.8 | findstr /r /c:"[0-9] *ms"` to force it to use `ping.exe`

Comment: additionally, `findstr` will give you hassles as well. I would use the errorlevel of the command instead `ping.exe -n 1 8.8.8.8 2>&1 >nul && echo Success || echo Oops`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advise for this task that the first line of your [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) looks like this:

```sh
@%SystemRoot%\System32\ping.exe -n 1 8.8.8.8 1>NUL || GoTo :EOF
```

This should end the script at the first line if the `ping` command line is unsuccessful.

You may additionally want to consider using a timeout function. If you open a Command Prompt window, type `ping /?` and press the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key, you should note that it has a `-w` option, which will accept a parameter in milliseconds.